# PHP- Arquivo upado não vai pro diretório definido

Tags: php, html, upload

```
$arquivocom = $_FILES['submetidocom']['name'];
    $diretoriocom = "C:/Users/NEWGRID/Documents/uploadcom/";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['submetidocom']['tmp_name'], $diretoriocom.$arquivocom);
    if (file_exists($arquivocom)){  
         echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Arquivo 2 já existente, por favor renomeio-o e tente novamente');</script>";

    }else{
         echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Upload 2 feito com sucesso!');</script>"; 
    }
```

HTML

```
                 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000">            
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="submetidocom" value="<?php echo $submetidocom; ?>" id="submetidocom" required="" autofocus="">
          </div>
```

Comment: Não apresenta nenhum erro ?

Comment: Não, o nome do arquivo e o diretório salva no banco mas o arquivo não vai pra pasta

Comment: Você usa o IIS no seu ambiente?

Comment: Como está setado a diretiva "upload_tmp_dir" no seu php.ini?

Comment: Não uso IIS, o "upload_tmp_dir" está assim: ;upload_tmp_dir =

Comment: Você tem permissão para escrever no  diretorio ?

Comment: Se você estiver tentando escrever em diretorios posteriores ao  raiz do seu site exemplo  seu site ta na pasta c:/localhost/meusite e tenta escrever em  em c:/usuairos/outrapasta vai dar problema caso não tenha permisssão de escrita

Comment: Tenho acesso sim

Comment: Verifique suas diretivas post_max_size, upload_max_filesize. Há uma lista de verificações que pode te ajudar, nesta questão aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531408/setting-php-tmp-dir-php-upload-not-working

Comment: Essas diretivas já havia alterado a algum tempo para poder importar o banco de dados.

Comment: Então, tente usar a função `copy()` em vez de `move_uploaded_file()` 
Assim: `copy($_FILES['submetidocom']['tmp_name'], $path);`

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas consegui resolver, acontece que estava colocando o move_uploaded_file antes da condição e deve ser colocado depois. Agora está funcionando correto.

Comment: Cara, que pegadinha do malandro n me atentei a isso. Porém, a sua pegunta diz uma coisa o seu problema era outro. Vendo aqui acredito que pelo menos um arquivo vc conseguia upar antes dw esbarrar no problema de n conseguir mais. Se isso fosse dito, esclareceria mais o problema. De qualquer forma, parabéns por ter encontrado e compartilhado a soluçao.